# Frequencies between 2 multiple response sets

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have a probably very simple problem, but my brain can not find an easy solution. I have survey data, consisting out of several multiple response sets. Looking like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(A_1 = c(1, NA, 1, NA),
                 A_2 = c(1, 1, NA, NA),
                 B_1 = c(1, 1, 1, NA),
                 B_2 = c(NA, 1, 1, NA))
```

Now i want to know how `df$B_1` and `df$B_2` are distributed for `df$A_1 == 1` and similarly for `df$A_1 == 2`.
I could of course do this one by one. But what I am searching for is a simple way to iterate over both, the A and the B colums. At best in one line of code.

```r
#Output:
# A_1 B_1 1
#     B_2 0.5
# A_2 B_1 1
#     B_2 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
df <- data.frame(A_1 = c(1, NA, 1, NA),
                 A_2 = c(1, 1, NA, NA),
                 B_1 = c(1, 1, 1, NA),
                 B_2 = c(NA, 1, 1, NA))

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(A_1) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum(!is.na(.))))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
    A_1   A_2   B_1   B_2
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     2     1
2    NA     1     1     1
```

Comment: that is not the outcome that I wanted, but it is close